# Quickly find last N occurrences of string in huge file in Linux

Tags: linux

I'm working with an application that generates gigantic log files (2.5GB per day). Occasionally, I need to gather info about the state of the app by searching through the log for select strings.

This is running on a small CentOS Linux system and since it's a production environment I want to minimize the CPU load of this type of search.

What is the most efficient way to find the last 50 occurrences of a string in a large file? The fastest I was able to come up with is this:

```
tac file.log | grep 'some string' -m50 | tac
```

Is that as fast as I'm going to get or are there better options?

Also, WHY is this fast? I expected the "tac" to reverse the whole file resulting in slower performance, but that does not appear to be the case.

**Update:**

An example scenario: say the application logs statistics about its memory utilization every 5 minutes. If I wanted to see the trends over the past hour, I would currently do something like this:

```
tac file.log | grep 'Memory' -m12 | tac
```

Comment: What's wrong with `tail`?

Comment: `tail` will show me the last few lines, not the lines which contain my string of interest

Comment: Why would you care about all the previous lines `grep` found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is good.  The reason `tac` isn't slow is that it doesn't need to read the whole file and reverse it.  Instead, it can seek to the last byte of the file and read backward from there.  And once your `grep` finds enough lines, it will stop, `SIGPIPE` will be raised in the first `tac`, and the remainder of the input file need not be read at all.

Comment: Just thinking if tail is not better solution when we have some idea how much lines is enough to read to get 50 occurrences ?

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj: The main problem is as you already said: we don't know how many lines to tail.  And it wouldn't be any better than the `tac` solution anyway, would it?

Comment: @kuldeep.kamboj: My previous attempt was `tail -n1000 file.log | grep 'Memory'` but that's not as efficient as it either doesn't grab enough lines, or grabs too many.